# compare two files (understanding)

Tags: awk, compare

I am trying to understand of awk comparsion of two fields from different files.
(all files are tab delimited)

1st file:

```
1   11796321
1   169549811
1   173917078
2   48962782
4   121696962
4   121697011
```

2nd file:

```
a 0 1 2 0 b 1 11796321 a
b 0 1 0 2 c 1 11800000 bd
c a d 0 0 2 4 121696962 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
 b 0 1 0 2 c 1 11800000 bd
```

So I would like to compare $1 and 2nd column from 1st file with 7th and 8th column in 2nd file and print unmatched.

I tried:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($7,$8) in a {next} {print $0}' file1 file2
```

Could you help understand where is mistake and how could I compare this files?
Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script you posted,it will work as you say you want in any POSIX awk. In what way is it not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the delimiter in both files are the same (`<tab>`), you can try this:

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{k=$1 FS $2;a[k];next} !($7 FS $8  in a)' file1 file2
```

Comment: It works perfectly. So at first I have to define k, where is FS (\t) and put it into array a, which is define by k and after that comparsion...Is it right?

Comment: @fedulka can you report which awk version are you using first?

Comment: awk version 4.0.1

Comment: @fedulka if it is gnu-awk(gawk) 4.0 should have already supported arrays of arrays, which means, your codes should work. If your awk is not gawk, or lower than 4, it won't work.

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific anywhere on this page (so far). No-one is using arrays of arrays (true multi-dimensional arrays), the question and all current answers use pseudo-multi-dimensional arrays as supported by all awk versions.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" -F'\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]; next} !(($7,$8) in a)' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you, your script works well. Always works. Thanks

Comment: You're not using `OFS` so no need to set it.